# How to implement Touch Screen functionality in WPF

Tags: wpf, touchscreen

I am using WPF 3.5 on Vista Machine. Can someone please let me know how to implement touch screen functionality on this. A demo example will be really helpful.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Touchscreens do nothing more than being a pointing device, so for your application it works exactly the same as using a mouse (MultiTouch is a different beast, though). What exactly do you want here?

Answer (score 1):

Touchscreen is like a mouse in all respects, except it can "teleport" the mouse pointer all over the place. Also, you can't have mouse hover effects with a touchscreen because it's impossible to move the cursor without clicking or dragging.

Comment: This might have been true in the old days it isn't any more. With advances like multi touch and gesture based computing, programming with touch in mind is very different than programming for a mouse. Especially if you want it to be good.

Answer (score 0):

You also need hardware that supports touch. This podcast is a good introduction to the technology from a .net perspective:

http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=469